# What is the most efficient regular expression to find two strings separated by 0 to n number of words?

Tags: python, regex

I've used a few permutations, but they all seem very slow. In short, I am looking for "foo" and "bar" separated by nothing, a word boundary, one or two words with the both words being potentially a partial match:

```
foobar -> Match
foo-bar -> Match
foo bar -> Match
foo biz bar -> Match
foo biz bang bar -> Match
foo biz bang bang bar -> No Match
foo-biz bar -> Match
FoO, bAr -> Match
Foos Baring -> Match
Foobizbangbarnit -> No match
Foobizbar -> Match
Arfoo bar -> No match
...
```

In reality, I need to match several combinations:

```
ant, bee
ant, cat
ant, dog
elephant, bee
elephant, cat
frog, bee
frog, cat
frog, dog
goat, hedgehog
```

A list of about 200 combinations in about 3 billion snippets of text. Using:

```
r'\bant\W{0,4}(\w*|\w+\W+\w+|\w+\W+\w+\W+\w+)(bee|cat|dog)|' +
r'\belephant\W{0,4}(\w*|\w+\W+\w+|\w+\W+\w+\W+\w+)(bee|cat)|' +
r'\bfrog\W{0,4}(\w*|\w+\W+\w+|\w+\W+\w+\W+\w+)(bee|cat|dog)|' +
r'\bgoat\W{0,4}(\w*|\w+\W+\w+|\w+\W+\w+\W+\w+)hedgehog'
```

Works, but is REALLY slow (~1,500 hours slow). Unfortunately, the combinations are not easy to nest. I am trying to create more liberal regular expressions that are faster so that I can pair down the 3 billion snippets to the anticipated 3-4 million and then maybe run the more rigorous regular expression on the subset, but any ideas are welcome. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why foo biz bang bang bar is no match?

Comment: @DevScheffer It's supposed to match up to a maximum of two words in-between, but not three or more.

Answer (score 0):

First, same question as comment, why `foo biz bang bang bar` is no match? And where are you expecting to put `bar`? I'm confused by you examples.

Maybe you can separate one regular expression into two, then match each candidate string with both two expression (whether or not such a separation will work depends on the restrictions you place on `bar`'s position, it seems that you want `foo` always at head of string)? By doing this you can avoid mathing characters in middle.

For example: `foo...bar` -> `^(?i)foo` + `(?i)bar`, (`(?i)` for [case insensitive](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html))

Comment: I answered @DevScheffer after you posted this. I'm looking for matches with a maximum of two words in between, so three or more words would not match.

Comment: @Gabe If it needs as your comment asks, then my answer is invalid and you can only use an expression to match. Perhaps you could try a **non-greedy mode (also known as lazy mode)** of regex, I drew drafts and found that non-greedy mode is more efficient when there are fewer characters after `bar` (or you could use it with `bar$` to match string endings).